# How do I fix this RegEx pattern, in order to extract all possible occurrences of a substring within a string that match this regex pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regexp-replace

My goal with this code is to replace only the occurrences of a substring that are preceded and followed by a specific pattern (to establish that pattern I have come up with the use of RegEx)

Actually I have already tried in many ways and I have not got good results, here I have used the `compile()` method to compile the RegEx pattern found in the input string into a regex pattern object (basically I extract 'one by one the occurrences of the substring' that I want to modify that meet the conditions of the RegEx pattern).

Then I can simply use the `replace()` function to, forgive the redundancy, replace the extracted substrings with the substring that I want

```py
import re

input_text = "y creo que hay 55 y 6 casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la 1 ,y las 27"

#the string with which I will replace the desired substrings in the original input string
content_fix = " "

##This is the regex pattern that tries to establish the condition in which the substring should be replaced by the other
#pat = re.compile(r"\b(?:previous string)\s*string that i need\s*(?:string below)?", flags=re.I, )
#pat = re.compile(r"\d\s*(?:y)\s*\d", flags=re.I, )
pat = re.compile(r"\d\s*(?:, y |,y |y )\s*(?:las \d|la \d|\d)", flags=re.I, )

x = pat.findall(input_text)
print(*map(str.strip, x), sep="\n") #it will print the substrings, which it will try to replace in the for cycle
content_list = []
content_list.append(list(map(str.strip, x)))
for content in content_list[0]:
    input_text = input_text.replace(content, content_fix) # "\d y \d"  ---> "\d \d"

print(repr(input_text))
```

This is the output that I get:

```
'y creo que hay 5  casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la  7'
```

And this is **the correct output that I need**:

```
'y creo que hay 55 6 casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la 1 27'
```

What changes should I make to my RegEx so that it extracts the correct substrings and suits the goals of this code?

Comment: I think using `re.sub()` is way better and simpler

Comment: `re.sub("ThePattern", "TheReplacement", "TheSOriginalString")`

Comment: @Justsomeone You're right, I just tried this `input_text = re.sub(r"\d\s*(?:, y |,y |y )\s*(?:las \d|la \d|\d)", content_fix, input_text)`  , and **it does the same thing as my code** but in much less lines (I didn't know it could be done like that), definitely **the problem is the RegEx** because it keeps throwing the same incorrect output... `'y creo que hay 5  casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la  7'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_text = "y creo que hay 55 y 6 casas, y quizas alguna mas... \
yo creo que empezaria entre la 1 ,y las 27"



re.sub(r'((\d+\s+)y\s+(\d+))| ((\d+\s+),y\s+\w{3}\s+(\d+))', r'\2\3 \5\6', input_text)


y creo que hay 55 6  casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la 1 27
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something and this is the best I could get :). You may find a way to improve it.
import re

```
input_text = "y creo que hay 55 y 6 casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la 1 ,y las 27"

print(re.sub(r"(?<=\d).+?(?=\d)", " ", input_text))
```

The output will look like this:

[image: Output form]

Maybe you will find a way to improve the expression or someone will..

Comment: Thank you very much, I will see what I can achieve with that, although trying with your regex I get this erroneous output `y creo que hay 5 6 1 27` en lugar de `y creo que hay 55 6 casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la 1 27`  :S

Comment: The tricky part is getting the regex to not grab this substring as well. `5 y 6 casas, y quizas alguna mas... yo creo que empezaria entre la `

Comment: @Matias Nicolas Rodriguez I think the tricky part is just to define the proper anchor (which I can't figure out.)

Comment: the proper anchor is: `(?:las |la )` `"a number"` `" y "` `"another number"`, for example, `"a eso de la 1 y 2 de la mañana"`, so the output is `"a eso de la 1 2 de la mañana"`, this replacement was possible because `"y"` **was in the middle**